# Possible to get sObjectName in Utility Bar LWC?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, sobject, record, utility-bar

I'm creating a LWC that I want to have context from the currently focused tab. I want to have both the `recordId` and the `sObjectName`.

In fact, **I've successfully done this for the `recordId`** based on [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/260200/89720) - it basically involves wrapping the LWC in an Aura component and passing `recordId` into the LWC from the Aura component.

However, this does not appear to be working for `sObjectName`, which is another implicit "marker" property. It works when I add the testAura component to a page normally, but not when I add it to the utility bar.

Here's all my code:

**testAura.cmp:**

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId, force:hasSObjectName, flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes, force:lightningQuickAction, lightning:utilityItem" access="global">
    <c:testLwc recordId="{!v.recordId}" sObjectName="{!v.sObjectName}" />
</aura:component>
```

**testAura.cmp-meta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<AuraDefinitionBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <description>Test Aura Component</description>
    <masterLabel>Test Aura Component</masterLabel>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
        <target>lightning__UtilityBar</target>
    </targets>
</AuraDefinitionBundle>
```

**testLwc.html**

```
<template>
    <div>recordId: <b>{recordId}</b></div>
    <div>sObjectName: <b>{sObjectName}</b></div>
</template>
```

**testLwc.js**

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class TestLwc extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    @api sObjectName;

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('recordId:', this.recordId);
        console.log('sObjectName:', this.sObjectName);
    }

}
```

**testLwc.js-meta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="KnowledgeSearch">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Test LWC</masterLabel>
    <description>Test LWC</description>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
        <target>lightning__UtilityBar</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

And here's a screenshot of the result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `force:hasSObjectName` is not supported in the utility bar context.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:hasSObjectName/documentation

So you would need to get the object name from the record id. You could call an Apex method that returns **sobjectName** based on record id.

For example

```
id recid = '0035e000008WyiAAAS';
system.debug(recid.getsObjectType());
```